# In which versions of ruby are external iterator speeds improved?

Tags: ruby, enumeration, ruby-1.9

According to [this rubyquiz](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz66.html), external iterators used to be slow, but are now faster. Is this an improvement only available in YARV (the C-based implementation of ruby 1.9), or is this also available in the C-based implementation of ruby 1.8.7?

Also, does `enum_for` rely on external iterators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 1.9 uses fibers to implement `Enumerator#next`, which might be better than Ruby 1.8, but still makes it an expensive call to make.

`enum_for` returns an `Enumerator` but does not rely on external iterators. A fiber/continuation will be created only if needed, i.e. if you call `next` but not if you call `each` or any other method inherited from `Enumerable`.

Rubinius and JRuby are optimizing `next` for the builtin types because it is very difficult to implement, in particular on the JVM. Fun bedtime reading: [this thread on ruby-core](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/vframe.rb/ruby/ruby-core/25769?25638-27714)

Answer (score 0):

Rubinius also has some major performance enhancements, but it is a Ruby 1.8 implementation, not 1.9.